# Bachmann's construction of the real numbers

Tags: analysis, foundations

On page 44 of [this](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/numbers) book an approach to constructing the real numbers as equivalence classes of nested rational intervals is outlined and attributed to Bachmann. The outline in the book is very rudimentary, in fact avoiding presenting the definition of the arithmetic operations and order in favour of comparing the constructions with the other more familiar ones.

So, can the reals be constructed as equivalence classes of nested rational intervals? if so is there a reference to the construction? and how painful are the details?

Comment: Doesn't the book say that it is Bachmanns construction? "Weierstrass uses the nesting of intervals to prove his theorem on limit points. Finally Bachmann in his [book title] introduces the real numbers by systematically making use of nested intervals."

Comment: I assume that every nest shall have lengths shrinking to $0$. Then every such nest is a filter basis for a minimal Cauchy filter on $\mathbb{Q}$, and an equivalence class of nests, I'd expect, consists of all nests generating the same minimal Cauchy filter. Thus you can construct $\mathbb{R}$ that way. If you go the filter way, the details are not too painful (but of course, that way is ahistorical).

Comment: see this: http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN577766198&DMDID=DMDLOG_0002

Comment: @DanielFischer what you are saying is that this construction by rational intervals can be compared directly to the completion of the rationals by means of minimal Cauchy filters. What I meant by asking if the construction works is whether the details of the proof can be given in terms of that construction, without recursing to other constructions. As an aside question, do you know of a systematic construction of the reals as minimal Cauchy filters of rationals? By that I mean giving an elementary proof of the complete ordered field axioms without using Bourbaki's approach to the reals.

Comment: @neptun thank you! This seems to conflict a bit with what is written on page 44, which got me confused.

Comment: The book probably references Bolzano for what is now called the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem. Bolzano seems a bit early to have defined the real numbers this way, but he proved the reals had the property.

Comment: @sanjab, thanks!! now I just need to brush up on my German.

Comment: @Ittay: It's fairly easy reading, though it does use some obsolete spellings and is a bit wordy by modern standards. The details turn out to be much like those for the Cauchy sequence approach.